# trying to exec fop via php - 'Can't connect to window server'

Tags: windows, remote-access, apache-fop, smb, cifs

I'm on Mac OSX 10.6,
I'm trying to generate a PDF from my Joomla PHP site, using exec to call fop via:

```
exec("fop -fo /temp/sample.fo -pdf /temp/doc".$now.".pdf > /temp/stdout.log 2> /temp/stderr.log");
```

but in the error logs I see:

```
Sat Jan  7 10:36:43 Georges-Mac.local java[8642] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1627)
    at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:263)
    at org.apache.xmlgraphics.java2d.GraphicContext.<init>(GraphicContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFGraphicContext.<init>(IFGraphicContext.java:42)
    at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.<init>(IFRenderer.java:128)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createRendererForDocumentHandler(RendererFactory.java:313)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.tryIFDocumentHandlerMaker(RendererFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createRenderer(RendererFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.<init>(RenderPagesModel.java:69)
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.setupModel(AreaTreeHandler.java:130)
    at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.<init>(AreaTreeHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createFOEventHandler(RendererFactory.java:359)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.<init>(FOTreeBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.createDefaultHandler(Fop.java:101)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.<init>(Fop.java:79)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newFop(FopFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.renderTo(InputHandler.java:109)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:174)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:205)
```

Any hints how to grant access to the 'window server'?  Or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, pass the [following argument](http://www.ve.com/kavachart/solutions/xwindows.html) to Java:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

You may need to [modify your command to start java directly](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/running.html#jar-option) instead of using the startup script in order to be able to do this.

Comment: ah yes, I'd forgotten that switch